# How Can I Add Objects To Another Object Using SAX After Parsing From XML With Java

Tags: java, xml, oop, sax

I am using SAX to parse an XML file and build objects from that data. I am building Room objects and placing Animal, NPC, and PC objects inside those Rooms based on the data from the XML file. I have been able to parse all data, create Room objects and Animal, NPC, and PC objects, but I am having difficulty placing the Animal, NPC, and PC objects inside the Room.

Here is a snippet of the XML file I am working with:

```
<room name="Violet" description="a large round room with violet draperies" state="half-dirty" north="Pig" east="Student" south="Teacher" west="Green">
    <animal name="Peter" description="a brown dog"/>
    <animal name="Lily" description="a black and white cat"/>
    <NPC name="Mary" description="a tall woman"/>
    <PC name="Squash" description="one who doesn't leave the animals and NPC-s alone"/>
</room>
```

And here is the code I am working with:

```
 public void endElement(String namespaceURI,
               String localName,
               String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("room")) {
        Room.State state;
        if (readState.equals("half-dirty")) {
            readState = "HALF_DIRTY";
            state = Room.State.valueOf(readState);
        } else {
        state = Room.State.valueOf(readState.toUpperCase());
        }

        Room room = new Room(readRoomName, readRoomDescription, state);

        roomMap.put(readRoomName.toLowerCase(), room);

        readRoomName = "";
        readRoomDescription = "";
        readState = "";
        readNorth = "";
        readSouth = "";
        readEast = "";
        readWest = "";

    }

    if (qName.equals("animal")) {
        Creature animal = new Animal(readAnimalName, readAnimalDescription);
        room.addCreature(animal);
    }

    if (qName.equals("NPC")) {
        Creature NPC = new NPC(readNPCName, readNPCDescription);
        room.addCreature(NPC);
    }

    if (qName.equals("PC")) {
        Creature PC = new PC(readPCName, readPCDescription);
        room.addCreature(PC);
    }
    }
```

Currently, my `addCreature()` method cannot find the `room` object because it is out of scope, and I understand that part, but I am lost on how to actually get the Animal, NPC, and PC objects placed into the Room object. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: declare `Room room` outside `if` ???

Comment: True, but then Room is not initialized, which causes another error.

Comment: You need to handle it the same way you handle `northMap` etc..